# How to display a progress bar on Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing an interface with Kivy. I try to place a progress bar at the top right ora text which and a number which evolves every second. Kind of like the example here: [Kivy custom shaders touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587933/kivy-custom-shaders-touch-events?rq=1). When I launch the application, the pogress bar is not visible.

Here is an example of what I'd like to be displayed.

main.py:

```
class Star:
    angle = 0
    distance = 0
    size = 0.1

    def __init__(self, sf, i):
        self.sf = sf
        self.j = 4 * i * sf.vsize
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.angle = 2 * math.pi * random()
        self.distance = 90 * random() + 10
        self.size = 0.05 * random() + 0.05

    def iterate(self):
        return range(self.j,
                     self.j + 4 * self.sf.vsize,
                     self.sf.vsize)

    def update(self, x0, y0):
        x = x0 + self.distance * math.cos(self.angle)
        y = y0 + self.distance * math.sin(self.angle)

        for i in self.iterate():
            self.sf.vertices[i:i + 3] = (x, y, self.size)
```

Comment: Post an example that doesn't include any unnecessary details (i.e. all of this drawing), and does include your attempt to display a progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add a `ProgressBar` to your display is to use a `Layout` as the root of your display rather than using the `Starfield` as root. So, if you define your display using a `kv` string like this:

```
kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Starfield:
        id: sf
        progress: pb
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        pos_hint: {'right':1.0, 'top':1.0}
        size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
'''
```

Then you can use that in your `build()` method:

```
class StarfieldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        EventLoop.ensure_window()
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.sf.update_glsl, 60 ** -1)
```

Note that the `Clock.schedule_interval()` argument has changed (since `Starfield` is no longer the root).

Then you can simply add updates to the `ProgressBar` in your `update_glsl()` method. Something like this:

```
self.progress.value += 1
```

will demonstrate the concept, but is obviously not the complete solution.

Comment: It worked when I tried it. What happens when you try it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have a black screen with the progress bar, but the stars have disappeared

Comment: In fact, I just want to add a progress bar at the top right of the application, or a text and a second counter.

Comment: Check that your `Clock.schedule_interval()` call has been changed.

Comment: The problem is just with initialize

Comment: With the modifications in my answer, the `root` of your `App` is now the `FloatLayout` from the `kv` string. That is why `self.root.initialize()` is showing an error. It looks like you might be able to replace that with `self.root.ids.sf.initialize()`.

Comment: I have one last question, because you are too strong: Is it possible to have multiple windows with your solution?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359950/how-do-i-have-multiple-windows-in-kivy).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change the color of the progress bar and the background?

Comment: Yes, but that should be posted as a separate question.